# Jupyter notebook does not load variables from bash_profile or zshrc

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables

I am running Jupyter notebook using VSCode. In order to run `rpy2`, I have to insert the following code in my notebook:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/'
```

I would prefer not to insert this into my scripts or notebooks every time as I am collaborating with others and I'm not sure if the above path is universal.

Anyway, I added the line

```
export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/
```

in my .bash_profile and .zshrc. I already applied source to these configuration files. However, Jupyter notebook still complains.

How can I modify what `os.environ` returns outside of my notebook? Can anyone direct me the path of the file that is being loaded by `os.environ` ? This way, I'll just export the variable R_HOME. I am using a conda environment too if that matters.

Advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the point in putting it into .zshrc, when you are using bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set environment variables for your conda environment, so create a `.env` file in the root directory and add this line:

```
R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/
```

this will specifically set the `R_HOME` variable for your conda environment, and also to find the loaded file path for `os.environ`, you can use the `inspect` module and modify that file to set the `R_HOME` variable.

```
import inspect
import os

print(inspect.getfile(os))
```

Comment: Thanks, awesome this solved my problem! I placed .env in the root of my project. When you say "root directory", do you mean in "/" ?